# Bitrix в почтовом шаблоне не отображается свойство товара

Tags: php, битрикс

Проблема заключается в том что я хочу запихнуть свойство товара(CML2_ARTICLE) в почтовый шаблон и по не понятным причинам оно просто не отображается, а вот CML2_ARTICLE2 почему то работает хотя оба свойства заполнены в товаре и по сути являются один в один одинаковыми. Добавляю новые переменные через php_interface/init.php и перехватываю письмо о новом заказе

Кто может подсказать в чём проблема?

**Код init.php**

```
<?
    AddEventHandler("sale", "OnOrderNewSendEmail", "ModifyOrderSaleMails");
    function ModifyOrderSaleMails($orderID, &$eventName, &$arFields)
    {
       if(CModule::IncludeModule("sale") && CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"))
       {
          $strOrderList = "";
          $dbBasketItems = CSaleBasket::GetList(
                     array("NAME" => "ASC"),
                     array("ORDER_ID" => $orderID),
                     false,
                     false,
                     array("PRODUCT_ID", "ID", "NAME", "QUANTITY", "PRICE", "CURRENCY", "CML2_ARTICLE","CML2_ARTICLE2")
                   );
     while ($arProps = $dbBasketItems->Fetch())
      {
      $summ = $arProps['QUANTITY'] * $arProps['PRICE'];
           $strCustomOrderList .= "<table><tr><td>".$arProps['ID']."</td><td>".$arProps['CML2_ARTICLE2']."</td><td>".$arProps['CML2_ARTICLE']."</td></tr></table>";
      }
      $arFields["HREN_NERABOTAET"] = $strCustomOrderList; 
} 
}?>
```

Comment: Чаще всего такая ошибка возникает из-за различий в имени свойства, прописанного в базе и вызываемого в коде. В частности, где-то может затесаться кириллическая С вместо латиницы...

Comment: @ВикторКарев этот вариант можно исключить копировал свойства прямо из списка свойств товара(и внешний и символьный код) и проверял они полностью на латинице

Comment: Ну, тогда создать тестовую страничку с CSaleBasket::GetList, и посмотреть, какие результаты выводятся. Проверить, что заданы именно свойства товара, а не другой сущности.

Comment: А так на вскидку и не скажешь, тут все зависит от того, как вы ложили в корзину товары. т.к. у товара может и есть это свойство, а вот в корзине оно совсем не обязательно появится. Надо разворачивать из списка товаров по индификатору их получить и от них уже получить свойства. Кроме того надо бы знать версию битрикса там есть ядро D7 и корзинка там вот просто совсем по другому получается.

Comment: @ВикторКарев и вправду нету этих свойств ,только всё равно не понятно как CML2_ARTICLE2 работает если его нет, спасибо за наводку попробую сам разобраться